# Check In App Purchase with a web service

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store

I need to design an app which use In App Purchase.
In this app I have to use StoreKit (obviously!) and also I want to store a list of people who bought app and check them with my own web service. This is because of some jailbreak feature which can delude app store

What I did comes in following:

**1. If user wants to use special feature and haven't bought it:**

1.1 First I check In User Defaults and Check If User purchased the feature.

1.2 If not I show him/her apple page store and ask him/her to buy.

1.3 After confirmation I send data to my web service and also save it in User Defaults.

**2. If user wants to use special feature and have bought it:**

2.1 First Check if anything has stored in User Defaults

2.2 If nothing has bought show him/her page store

2.3 After getting has already purchased message from store I check it with my web service

2.4 If web service confirmed already purchased message then I let user use feature and save it in User Defaults.

**I have problem with choosing a unique identifier which works among all apple devices.**

Comment: identifierForVendor should work fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to identify the device, you need to validate the transaction.  The user should be able to restore purchases across re-installations and across devices.

The [In-App Purchase programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW3) states -

> **Persisting Using Your Own Server** Send a copy of the receipt to your server along with some kind of credentials or identifier so you
>   can keep track of which receipts belong to a particular user. For
>   example, let users identify themselves to your server with an email or
>   user name, plus a password. Don’t use the identifierForVendor property
>   of UIDevice—you can’t use it to identify and restore purchases made by
>   the same user on a different device, because different devices have
>   different values for this property.

So, once you have the receipt you can send it to a web service.  You can use a shared secret or a public/private key pair to sign the receipt so that your server can validate it.

Comment: I still don't know what to use as unique identifier? Is apple's receipt a unique identifier?

Comment: The receipt from the iTunes store contains a unique identifier for the transaction - original_transaction_id - See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1.  If you want to further identify a particular user then you will need to ask them for an email address or username.